# Dealing with insulting behavior by a moderator

Tags: discussion

In a comment on this answer,

https://chess.stackexchange.com/a/34553/1954

I wrote:

> Your methodology doesn't seem convincing to me. Personal, subjective retrospection with a sample size of one doesn't tell us much. Frequency counts at different times don't tell us whether it's the standards that are changing or the strength of the players. And in any case, 10 years is a very short time.

The author of the answer replied in a comment with a personal insult:

> @BenCrowell I guess your reading skills aren't that good else you would have seen that I say the same in my answer

This is a classic example of bad behavior on an SE site: a comment criticizes an answer, and the author of the answer replies with a personal attack.

The interesting issue is that in this case the author is a moderator. I've flagged the comment, but how does this play out when the person whose comment has been flagged is a moderator? Does the moderation get assigned to some other moderator to look at?

Answer (score 1):

Look in the mirror. Your initial comment was abusive and attention seeking. Both comments now deleted.